# How to use capture amino acid frequencies inside a for loop using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, bioinformatics

I have a simple code which captures amino acid frequencies of each column of multiple sequence alignment and stores it in a matrix. I have a vector called `amino` which stores different amino acid types:

```
amino=['A','R','N','D','C','Q','E','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V','Gaps']
```

I'm using Matlab's built-in function to capture frequencies of each element:

```
aacount(optimal(:,2),'Gaps',true).A % return the frequency of A in 2nd column
```

What I want to do is get the same output using `amino` vector index. Something like this:

```
aacount(optimal(:,2),'Gaps',true).index(1)
```

This approach gives the following error:

> 'Reference to non-existent field'.

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I fixed this as @frslm has suggested down below. But when I'm using this function inside a for loop instead of giving a fixed index number, it gives an error as 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals'. Any ideas how to fix this and use the function inside a loop.

Comment: Could you show your for-loop code, either here or in a new question?

Comment: @frslm

    for i=0:1:5
                for j=0:1:21
                    temp=aacount(optimal(:,i),'Gaps',true);
                    optimal_mtx(j,i)=temp.(amino(j))
                end
            end

Comment: Ah, MATLAB indices start at 1, not 0. Your for-loop iterators should look like this: `for i=1:5` and `for j=1:21`.

Comment: @frslm Thank you very much. I'm not familiar with Matlab. However, it is working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic field reference (`.()`) in this case. To build on your example, the following returns the frequency of Alanine (amino acid 'A') obtained from `aacount()`:

```
aacount(optimal(:,2),'Gaps',true).(amino(1))
```

Comment: It worked didn't work in one line. But worked as follows,

    ex=aacount(optimal(:,1),'Gaps',true);
    ex.(amino(1))

Comment: Yes, I know. But it didn't work in one line. I rechecked now. Another thing is I want to use this inside a for loop. So I can use loop value instead of using a fixed index value. But it gives an error as 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals'. Any idea how to fix this?